# php mysqli code to add more than 100 contacts my code shows error

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5, mysqli

If i add 50 contacts to my code it will work but whenever i add more than 100 contacts it will show error.

here is my code :

```
function CreateContactList($UserNumber,$query){

        $conn = $this->connect_db();
        if(!empty($query)){
        mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM contactlist WHERE `UserNumber`='".$UserNumber."'");

        $querys = "INSERT INTO contactlist (`UserId`, `UserNumber`, `ContactNumber`, `ContactName`) VALUE ".$query;
        $querys1 = substr($querys, 0, -1);
        }
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $querys1)){
                $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                    $result['msg'] = 'success';
            }else{
                $result['msg'] = 'error';
            }
        return $result;
    }
```

........................................

```
case "CreateContactList":
        $model = new Model();
        $data = $_REQUEST;
        $UserNumber = $_REQUEST['UserNumber'];
        $UserId = '1';
        unset($data['UserNumber'],$data['UserId'],$data['action']);
        $query = '';
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            //$insertdata[] = array('ContactName' => $key,'ContactNumber' => $value,'UserNumber' => $UserNumber,'UserId' => $UserId );
            $query .= "('".$UserId."','".$UserNumber."','".FilterPhone($key)."','".$value."'),";
        }
        //print_r($query);
        $return = $model->CreateContactList($UserNumber,$query);
        error_log(date('d-m-Y h:i A').'_response_'.print_r($return, TRUE) , 3, $log_file);
        $return = FilterArray($return);
        print_r(JsonReturn($return));
    break;
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong in code .

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: it does not add contacts if i insert more 100 and more.but it work fine if i insert 50 contacts

Comment: error it will show: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Arra' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be running into string-handling problems in PHP, which is really an algorithm problem, not a language one. Basically, when working with large strings, you want to minimize unnecessary copying. Primarily, this means you want to avoid concatenation. The fastest and most memory efficient way to build a large string, such as for inserting hundreds of rows at one, is to take advantage of the implode() function and array assignment.

```
    $query = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
       $query[] = "('".$UserId."','".$UserNumber."','".FilterPhone($key)."','".$value."'),";
    }
    $return = $model->CreateContactList($UserNumber,$query);
```

Comment: sir could you implement your code in my code so that i come to know where i am doing wrong

Comment: @nidhimahajan, can you please share exactly what error you are getting, put this die(mysqli_error($conn)); instead of $result['msg'] = 'error';

Comment: error it will show: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Arra' at line 1

Comment: @nidhimahajan instead of calling like this $return = $model->CreateContactList($UserNumber,$query); use this $return = $model->CreateContactList($UserNumber, impload(",", $query));

Comment: now it will show internal server errror @krishnaraj

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have batch insert instead of running insert query one by one

Below is SQL query, but you can map it to PHP easily

```
INSERT INTO contactlist (`UserId`, `UserNumber`, `ContactNumber`, `ContactName`)  
           VALUES(1, '0001111111', '000111111', 'Name 1'), 
    (2, '0002222', '0002222', 'Name 2'), 
    (3, '0003333', '00033333', 'Name 3')
```